# Change language on SharePoint Foundation 2013 SP1

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, language, fim

Can you change the core language? I managed to download a Swedish version of SharePoint Foundation 2013 SP1 and install it.

Now I'm having problem with installing Forefront Identity Manager portal and service because it says the language is not supported.

I tried installing the English language pack, but it is still in Swedish.

Do I have to re-install everything?

Comment: Have you tried changing the language from Internet Explorer options?

Comment: Yes. English is selected as display language (but still Swedish in the Central Administration page). The problem is that even the configuration wizard is in Swedish.

Comment: Try running SharePoint Configuration Wizard

Comment: I did and this is the one I downloaded and followed: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=42256. But I dont thinks it change anything in the core.

The error that I receive from the FIM installation is:
"An exception occurred while running Microsoft.IdentityManagement.SolutionPackUtility.exe: Språket stöds inte på servern. (The language is not supported on the server)"

Comment: what is server language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once it is created you cannot change it easily.  You have to back up the content database and reattach it with the new LCID attached (1033 for english)

[Here is an artical which explains how to do it.](http://whitepages.unlimitedviz.com/2014/03/how-to-change-the-language-for-a-sharepoint-site/)  Good Luck!